# Texture Description for mapping texture and passing data to the GPU

Tags: graphics, textures, directx-11, texture-mapping, render-to-texture

I'm using DirectX11 and I've got a few problems with the Map / Unmap functions.

First question is should I be using Map / Unmap or UpdateSubresource? Google has brought up pages where people say one is quicker than the other so I am absolutely unsure which is quicker.

Answered (see my comment to this).

<del>Question 2:
I need to manipulate a texture on the CPU and send it to the GPU and then render it. My texture flags are as follows.</del>

```
textureDesc.Width = textureWidth;
textureDesc.Height = textureHeight;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
```

<del>The texture creates fine but when I run the "Map" function I get the error "One or more arguments are invalid.".</del>

Answered (see my comment to this).

<del>Question 3. I have the following code to write to the texture (simply test code), are there any problems with it?</del>

```
result = deviceContext->Map(m_renderTargetTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);

FLOAT* pTexels = (FLOAT*)mappedResource.pData;
for( UINT col = 0; col < 20; col++ )
{
    pTexels[col*4 + 0] = 1; // Alpha
    pTexels[col*4 + 1] = 1; // Blue
    pTexels[col*4 + 2] = 1; // Green
    pTexels[col*4 + 3] = 1; // Red
}

deviceContext->Unmap(m_renderTargetTexture, 0);

D3DX11SaveTextureToFile( deviceContext, m_renderTargetTexture, D3DX11_IFF_JPG, L".\.\FILE.jpg");
```

Final question is more an inquiry as to best practise. I need to send an array of data (1D, 2D and eventually 3D). My question here is what is the best way to send my data to the GPU from the CPU. Through a texture created on the CPU and then passed to the GPU? Or is there some other means that is better?

Thanks.

---

Working code for question 3. However attempting to create a render target view using this texture fails, I am unsure why yet. Almost certainly to do with the description I am using.

```
UCHAR* pTexels = (UCHAR*)mappedResource.pData;
for( UINT row = 0; row < textureDesc.Height; row++ )
{
    //Row number * height
    UINT rowStart = row * mappedResource.RowPitch;
    for( UINT col = 0; col < textureDesc.Width; col++ )
    {
        //width * number of channels (r,g,b,a)
        UINT colStart = col * 4;
        pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = 255; // Red
        pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = 0; // Green
        pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = 0; // Blue
        pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = 255; // Alpha
    }
}
```

Comment: Question2: The problem was the Usage and the CPUAccessFlags. Usage has to be set to D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC and CPUAccessFlags set to D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE.

Comment: For question 3 see the added code on the main post.